# Java Servlet - Print to Eclipse console

Tags: java, servlets

I'd like to test my servlet by printing the results to the console. System.out.println does not seen to work for a servlet. Does anyone know how I can achieve this? Main purpose is for debugging at a later stage.

```
public class GetAllStaff extends HttpServlet {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

static StaffDAO dao = new StaffDAO();
static ArrayList<Staff> sList = null;

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException {

    sList = dao.getAllStaff();

    for (int i = 0; i < sList.size(); i++)
    {

    }
  }
```

Comment: Why not just connect the debugger when you want to debug? Generally, you'd use a logger (like log4j, logback and/or slf4j) for *logging*. Also, because there could be multiple `Servlet` instances in the pool at runtime, is your `dao` thread safe?

Comment: @Elliot: That pool is only true when the servlet implements the since Servlet 2.4 (2003!) deprecated `SingleThreadModel` interface. Nonetheless, making it static is indeed fishy.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
ServletContext context = getServletContext( );
context.log("This is a log item");
```

The logs are not printed in Eclipse console but can be found at logs folder of servlet container (say Apache Tomcat)

Reference: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-debugging.htm

Answer (score 0):

You may want to print everything on a browser with the following code?

```
PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
out.println("Some information on the browser...");
```

P.S I tried `System.out.println("something");` in my IDE (Intellij), the result showed up in the console.

Comment: What is `res` (what is the type/instantiation)?